# call mono_method(pointer) from c

Tags: c#, c, pointers, mono, unsafe

i have mono code

`public static unsafe int* mono_method (int* p)

{

//....

return p;

}`

and want to call it from native c

`MonoObject *result = mono_runtime_invoke(mono_method, NULL, args, NULL);`

I tried out some different pointers, variables in the args flag (should be void**)
but always get SIGSEGV error when i execute the runtime invoke.

My question is: 
Is it possible to pass pointers from c to mono via runtime_invoke and how?

best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have tested everything except what the documentation says at 
http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono: The params array contains the arguments to the method with the same convention: MonoObject* pointers for object instances and pointers to the value type otherwise.

```
void* args[1];
int val = 10;
MonoObject *result;
args [0] = &val;
result = mono_runtime_invoke(mono_method, NULL, args, NULL);
/* result will be a boxed IntPtr since pointer types can't be boxed themselves */
```

Comment: Hmm, well then the next question would be, is it possible to pass a pointer to function instead of pointer to int and execute the function in the mono code?

Answer (score 0):

This question was just asked here, but [take a look this for the answer](http://www.huronbox.com/~james/techdemos/cs-callback.html).